# Run PHP file onClick() jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, onclick

Hello I'm struggling to get this to work:

html:

```
<button type="submit" name="Report" id="printReport" class="btn btn-success bg-gradient btn-sm rounded-0"><i class="fa-solid fa-print"></i>Print</button>
```

PHP
`dailyReportPDF.PHP` - external PHP file.

jQuery

```
    $("#printReport").click(function(e) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "dailyReportPDF.PHP",
      });
  });
```

I am pretty new to jQuey/Ajax. Can I call like above? it does not show up any error in a console either. it's simply to generate a pdf document.

*Note : If i assign as a hyperlink on button click it does works as it should.

```
<button type="button" name="Report" id="printReport" class="btn btn-success bg-gradient btn-sm rounded-0"><i class="fa-solid fa-print"></i><a href="dailyReportPDF.php" style="text-decoration:none">Print</a></button>
```

works well.

Comment: *can I* - yes, that's how you make an ajax call.  It appears the info your missing is that the *result* of that call will return to your *javascript*, not the browser, so you then need code to display that result (eg in a popup, or a "pdf viewer" component).  If you simply want to open the link in the browser then use `location.href = "dailyReportPDF.php"` instead of ajax.